# Iterate through an object recursively to find child, picking up parents, grandparents etc along the way

Tags: javascript

I have an object which comprises of a menu.

I want to enter a `category ID` and get the `category name`, then move backwards to find it's `parents`. That's not easy within an object so I'm thinking to catch the `parents` along the way instead.

The problem I have is how to `reset` the `parents` when the end child is not found and there's nowhere else to go.

This is what I'm trying:

```js
var data = [
 {
        "tree_id": "10",
        "name": "babies & children",
        "parent": null,
        "position": "1"
    }, {
        "tree_id": "2",
        "name": "clothing",
        "parent": null,
        "position": "1",
        "children": [{
            "tree_id": "15",
            "name": "kids",
            "parent": "2",
            "position": "3",
            "children": [{
                "tree_id": "78",
                "name": "fourToTen",
                "parent": "15",
                "position": "3",
                "children": [{
                    "tree_id": "102",
                    "name": "fourToSix",
                    "parent": "78",
                    "position": "3"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "tree_id": "55",
        "name": "toys",
        "parent": null,
        "position": "1",
        "children": [{
            "tree_id": "35",
            "name": "lego",
            "parent": "55",
            "position": "3"
        }]
    }
];

var crumbs = [];
function getParts(data, elem) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];
        if(obj.children !== undefined){
            /* push parent into crumbs */
            crumbs.push(obj.name);
         if(obj.children[0].tree_id === elem){
             /* if we've found what we're looking, we're done */
                crumbs.push(obj.children[0].name);
                console.log(crumbs);
            } else {
             /* reset parents */
                crumbs = []; /* <-- this is wrong here */
                /* not found, keep recursing */
             getParts(obj.children, elem);
            }
        }
    }
}
/* I want this to return
 [
  "clothing",
  "kids",
  "fourToTen",
  "fourToSix"
 ]

 but it returns
 [
  "fourToTen",
  "fourToSix"
 ]
*/
getParts(data, '102');
```

The question is, how can I save the `parents` array until I'm at the end of the line and the child is not found, and reset it then?

[Here's a fiddle if that's your preferred playround](https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/92n1pug8/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `category id = tree_id` and `category_name = name`

You'll need to treat your `data` object like a tree, then transverse it and track the parents along the way. If something is found then dump the information you need.

So `data` is basically an array of objects you will be transversing.

**Example:**

```
"use strict";
var data = [
    {
        "tree_id": "10",
        "name": "babies & children",
        "parent": null,
        "position": "1"
    },
    {
        "tree_id": "2",
        "name": "clothing",
        "parent": null,
        "position": "1",
        "children": [{
            "tree_id": "15",
            "name": "kids",
            "parent": "2",
            "position": "3",
            "children": [{
                "tree_id": "78",
                "name": "fourToTen",
                "parent": "15",
                "position": "3",
                "children": [{
                    "tree_id": "102",
                    "name": "fourToSix",
                    "parent": "78",
                    "position": "3"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "tree_id": "55",
        "name": "toys",
        "parent": null,
        "position": "1",
        "children": [{
            "tree_id": "35",
            "name": "lego",
            "parent": "55",
            "position": "3"
        }]
    }
];

// Solution 
function transverse(root, tree, targetId) {
    tree.push({
        catId : root.tree_id,
        catName : root.name
    });

    /* this if() must come first otherwise fails if you want to stop before end */
    if (root.tree_id === targetId) {
        console.log("Found id:" + targetId+ ", name=" + root.name);
        console.log("Dumping parent info => " + JSON.stringify(tree));
        return tree;
    }

    if (root.hasOwnProperty("children") && root.children instanceof Array)
        root.children.forEach(child => {
            transverse(child, tree, targetId);
        });

}

data.forEach(item => {
     transverse(item, [], /*Looking for Id=*/"102");
});

console.log("done");
```

**Output:**

```
Found id:102, name=fourToSix
Dumping parent info => 
[
  {"catId":"2","catName":"clothing"},
  {"catId":"15","catName":"kids"},
  {"catId":"78","catName":"fourToTen"},
  {"catId":"102","catName":"fourToSix"}]
]
```

Comment: Globals are bad, try rewriting your function so that `wantId` is passed as a parameter.

Comment: Indeed globals are bad.

Comment: Updated answer, left a comment

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I see what you meant there. Thanks for pointing it out. Hope it is helping u solve your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a compact functional way:

```js
data = [{"tree_id":"10","name":"babies & children","parent":null,"position":"1"},{"tree_id":"2","name":"clothing","parent":null,"position":"1","children":[{"tree_id":"15","name":"kids","parent":"2","position":"3","children":[{"tree_id":"78","name":"fourToTen","parent":"15","position":"3","children":[{"tree_id":"102","name":"fourToSix","parent":"78","position":"3"}]}]}]},{"tree_id":"55","name":"toys","parent":null,"position":"1","children":[{"tree_id":"35","name":"lego","parent":"55","position":"3"}]}]

// 

first = (ary, fn) => ary.reduce((r, x) => r || fn(x), false);

locate = (data, id) => _locate({children: data}, id, []);

_locate = (node, id, path) => node.tree_id === id ? path
    : first(node.children || [], n => _locate(n, id, path.concat(n)));

res = locate(data, '102').map(n => n.name)
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Am I likely to run into browser compatibility issues with this?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - looking at the source code you'll be fine as `Array.reduce`,`Array.concat` and `Array.map` are all ECMA 5.1 syntax. @georg 's solution is based on the functional programming concept and that's all.